# ambiguous call between functions error

Tags: c#, nullable

I got this question in a interview, now i know i gave wrong answer.
Why is this program showing ambiguous call between functions and therefore not compiling?

```
public static void Display(int? num) {
    Console.WriteLine(num);
}

public static void Display(string num) {
    Console.WriteLine(num);
}

static void Main() {
    Display(1);
    Display("1");
    Display(null);

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This statement  `Display(null);` can be interpreted as either `Display(nullable int with null value)` or `Display(string with null value)`. Hence the ambiguous call error.

Comment: In order to give this error not only do there have to be multiple applicable methods, there also has to be *no best method*. Since neither int? nor string is clearly "better" than the other, the methods are ambiguous. If it were instead object and string then string would be better because it is more specific than object.